# Find Res $(f,0)$ if $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z^8}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I also have a question that I ask for help to check it.

Find Res $(f,0)$ if $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z^8}$.

Given that $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z^8}$, I found out that the isolated singularity $z = 0$ is a pole of order 8 and so what I did is

$Res (f,0) = \frac{1}{(8-1)!} \cdot \frac{d^7}{dz^{7}} \left(z^8 f(z) \right)_{z=0} = \frac{1}{7!} \cdot \frac{d^7}{dz^{7}} \left(z^8 \frac{\sin z}{z^8} \right)_{z=0} = \frac{1}{7!} \cdot \frac{d^7}{dz^{7}} \left(\sin z \right)_{z=0}$.

If $g(z) = \sin z$. Then $g^{(7)} = -\cos z$. So,

$Res (f,0) = \frac{1}{7!} (-\cos z)_{z=0} = - 1/7!$.

Is this correct?  Or can somebody point out my mistake?  I would truly appreciate your kindness.

Comment: It is correct. Residue is also the coefficient of $\frac 1z$ in the Laurent series. When you expand $\sin z$ in its Taylor series you get the residue without any differentiation!

Comment: Thank so much @KaviRamaMurthy. So much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It usually could be much easier to use the Taylor series of $sin(z)$. Write
$$\frac{sin(z)}{z^8}=\frac{1}{z^8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n-7}}{(2n+1)!}$$
You got a Laurent series of a meromorphic function. The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, which in our case, corresponds to $n=3$. So we get:
$$Res(f,0)=\frac{(-1)^3}{(2\cdot 3+1)!}=-\frac{1}{7!}$$
And as you see, this is identical to your result.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much @GSofer .  I really appreciate this.